# How to highlight something which is inside a pair of brackets in latex?

Tags: highlighting, brackets

I know the way to highlight "something" using `\hl{something}`. However, if "something" is inside another pair of brackets already, I cannot add another pair of bracket like:

`{ \hl{something} }`.

I build the pdf file using the "pdfLatex" compiler in TeXworks and got this error when using brackets in side brackets:

> ! Argument of \T@ref has an extra }.

To be more specific, I want to highlight some sentences inside an abstract of a paper. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code, that shows what you've tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Why can't you add another pair of `{}`?  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  Also, you could use `\tikzmark` to mark points in the text and then do the higlighting.

Comment: There isn't usually any problem with nesting curly brackets .... TeX would expire without the mazes of their entanglements.

Comment: I build the pdf file using the "pdfLatex" compiler in TeXworks and got this error when using brackets in side brackets:

! Argument of \T@ref has an extra }.

Comment: The info you gave us aren't sufficient, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (click on this link to know how to build it). Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.